# Pass Parse server Current User object from Route to others

Tags: slim, parse-server

I am using Slim framework With parse server php SDK

I want to pass current user object after user login the parse server 
How I can retrieve this object in any routes in Slim $app?
So I can identify the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the Solution to do that

Staring the session in the top of index.php file in the Slim Application

Then I can access the current user object From parse server php sdk